# Arcmap: attach python script to a button?

Tags: python, arcmap

In ArcMap 9.x how can I attach a python script to a button?

Comment: What do you mean by a button?  The easiest way to integrate a python script into ArcMap is through Toolbox.  Is that okay?

Comment: no, not through a toolbox. that takes up too much screen real estate.

Comment: arcmap 10 version of this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1697/create-a-button-using-arcobjects-in-python-arcmap-10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works in VBA to run a Python script.  Just call the subroutine with a button.

```
Private Sub python_Click()
    Shell "C:\Python25\python.exe ""C:\rowcount.py"
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is a good example of why this stack exchange platform works. I [had an answer ready](http://www.yukongis.ca/How_To/Attach_python_script_to_a_button), but this one is simpler and cleaner. Thanks :)

Comment: What about .net? Any code snippets?

Answer (score 5):

As @fmark says, the easiest way to integrate a Python script into ArcMap is through a toolbox, which I'd recommend.

That said, if you really need to (eg, you need a nicer front end than the toolbox) you have two options:

1. You can call the script as a command line argument from another program that is linked to the button - the easiest would be VBA.
2. You can add the Python script to the toolbox, and call the custom toolbox from your button (VBA, VB.Net, C#.Net).

Still, I'd go with @fmark and just add the script to the toolbox given the choice.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it in C# would be like this using the ArcGIS template for a button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RunEditPython
   {    
    public class PythonEdited : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    {

    public PythonEdited()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\temp\\WHP\\WellsEdited.py");
    }
    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
        Enabled = ArcMap.Application != null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks! and welcome to GIS stack exchange. I hope you find your time here fruitful; you've certainly come bearing gifts, it's appreciated.