# Making button that calls Python script as command rather than script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, python-script-tool

I believe that in Arc9.3, commands could be created using VBA scripts. To add a custom command, you would navigate to Customize > Toolbars > Customize... and click UIControls. However, UIControls is not there in version 10.

I am creating two separate scripts for a map book project. One script will save the layout settings to a table, and the other will update the layout with settings from the same table. I want both of these scripts to be commands assigned to buttons in a toolbar. I created them as script tools, but whenever I click on them, they run the script as a geoprocessing tool. It brings up a progress window, and it takes about 10 times longer to execute than if I had run the code in the Python command line window. I don't want the progress window or the much longer execution time.

How can I make it so that the script isn't considered a "tool" and is instead a command similar to the Save button?

Answer (score 6):

Within an Excel VBA macro, the following calls a Python script called `test.py`:

```
Sub test()

rsp = Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c C:/test.py", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

(Original source [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=309878))
I've forgotten how to run an ArcGIS VBA module, but perhaps a similar line would work to call your python script.

---

Another strategy that might work could be to compile your python script to an executable (.exe) or batch file (.bat) and call it then.

---

I just saw another [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401/arcmap-attach-python-script-to-a-button/424#424) on gis.se that is more elegant:

> ```
> Private Sub python_Click()
>     Shell "C:\Python25\python.exe ""C:\rowcount.py"
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a complete GIS newb, but I came across this in the documentation:

[You can make your script tools run faster by running them in process. This topic describes in-process execution.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Running_a_script_in_process/00150000000r000000/)