# It is possible to edit selected features with Python?

Tags: python, arcpy, python-2.6

I'm trying to edit some fields of the selected features in ArcMap. It's possible to do this with Python (ArcPy)?

Comment: What type of edit do you want to do?  It would be easy to create an update cursor, select your data, modify it, then put it back.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can edit selected features using ArcPy inside ArcMap. Create a toolbox with a "Feature Layer" data type parameter. When you run the tool, select the layer from within ArcMap. The selected set of that layer will be present when the script executes.

Comment: What if I just want to create a button that, after manually selecting features, when pressed, will change the value to a field of those selected features? I can do that too with Python?

Comment: Yes, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401/arcmap-attach-python-script-to-a-button/424#424 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/how-to-make-a-button-that-calls-a-python-script-as-a-command-rather-than-a-script